# Is there a function satisfying as follows?

Tags: calculus

I have a question. Is there a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $c_1|x|\leq (f(x))^2\leq c_2 |x|$ for some positive constant $c_1,c_2$, and $$ \int_0^{\infty}(f'(x))^2dx<\infty$$
?

Comment: $f^2(x) = f \circ f(x)$ or $\left(f(x)\right)^2$?

Comment: tks. I edited my post. 
(f(x))^2

Answer (score 1):

In fact, isn't a differentiable function in $\Bbb R$ with $c_1|x|\leq (f(x))^2\leq c_2 |x|$ because this implies $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0)$ does not exists:
$$
\left|\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}\right| =
\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|\ge\frac{\sqrt c_1}{\sqrt{|x|}}.
$$